# Password Hashing and Password Verifying

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I hashed a password through

```
$hashedpassword = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

This stores the password as a hashed value into a database.
But when I try to login in through

```
$Password=$_POST['Password'];

$hashedpassword = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if(password_verify($Password, $hashedpassword))
```

It will always tell me that the password is correct, regardless on whether it is or not.
Is there a way around this, so I can hash the password but login with  the entered (non-hashed) password.

Comment: It looks like you're rehashing when you try the login, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're re-hashing the password each time the user logs in.

Comment: [Here is a tutorial for how to do this](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)

Answer (score 2):

At some point in the past, when the account was created or when the password was last changed, you should have **stored** the hashed password.

You need to get the stored password hash from the database and use that with `password_verify`.

Currently, you are hashing the newly submitted password and verifying the submitted password against that, so of course, it always matches.